# Having two queries on the same page

Tags: php

I'm still pretty new to CI. One of my friends told me to start looking into it. I'm trying to convert a site I just did in PHP over to CI. But I keep running into problems.

Every google search I try I can't seem to find a result.

I have 2 different queries that I need to have on the same page.

My model

```
class Fittv_model extends CI_Model
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

function get_fittv_chain()
{
    //get all entry
    $club_id = $_GET['club_id'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM company_details WHERE id = '$club_id'");
    return $query->result();
}

function get_last_installs()
{
    //this will get the last 3 installs
    $club_id = $_GET['club_id'];
    $last_installs = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fit_tv_locations WHERE club_id = '$club_id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3");
    return $last_installs->result();
}
```

My controller.

```
class Fittv extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('fittv_model');
        ##$data['query'] = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
        $data = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
        $data = $this->fittv_model->get_last_installs();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('fittv/index', $data);
    }
}
```

Problem is I do not have a clue on how to get the 2 different models to view on the view page.

My current error is as follows:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: last_installs
Filename: fittv/index.php
Line Number: 23
```

Then here is a simple view below that I am trying to see the data with

```
<?php
    foreach ($last_installs->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->location_name;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're assigning twice to the `$data` variable. Also, in you model you duplicated the constructor's code.

Comment: Please review your model code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `associative array` for assigning values

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('fittv_model');
    ##$data['query'] = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
    $data['chain'] = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
    $data['installs'] = $this->fittv_model->get_last_installs();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('fittv/index', $data);
}
```

And in view page use `$chain` and `$installs` variable.

[Codeigniter Views](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your model.
And you should prefer CodeIgniter [Active Record Method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) Class for performing database queries.

```
class Fittv_model extends CI_Model
{    
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }


  function get_fittv_chain()
  {
   $tablename = 'yourTable';
   //get all entry
   $club_id = $_GET['club_id'];
   $query = $this->db->get_where($tablename, array('id' => $club_id));
   return $query->result();
  }

  function get_last_installs()
  {
  //this will get the last 3 installs
    $club_id = $_GET['club_id'];
    $last_installs = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fit_tv_locations WHERE club_id =              '$club_id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3");  //Convert this also
  return $last_installs->result();
   } 
}
```

And you **must pass assosiative array** from your controller to your view.

```
class Fittv extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
$this->load->model('fittv_model');
##$data['query'] = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
$data['chain'] = $this->fittv_model->get_fittv_chain();
$data['install'] = $this->fittv_model->get_last_installs();
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('fittv/index', $data);
```

}
   }

In your view, your data will be available under variable name **$chain and $install** (Whatever key you give to your data array becomes variable in your view).

Comment: I figured it out with both of you results. I will look into the Active Record option. Right now I'm just trying some stuff so I will stick a bit with the standard mySQL query till I read more on the active records. lots to learn.

Thanks for your help Shivam and Yogesh

Comment: I also found that this line didn't work
   $query = $this->db->get_where($tablename, array('id' => '$club_id'));

I had to take out the quotes where $club_id was so that it was 'id' => $club_id

Comment: Yeah, Typo error, $club_id will come without quotes, its a variable. Thanks, edited the code.